# C++ : Do functions have a value?

Tags: c++, function

I wrote a simple code that checks if a number is 10 . If it is, the function returns 10.

```
int foo()
{
   if (n==10)
      return n;
}
```

I wrote another function to check if a number is a palindrome

```
int checkpalin(int n)
{
       int temp=n;
       double rev=0;
       while (temp)
       {
           int d=temp%10;
           rev=rev*10+d;
           temp/=10;
       }
       if (rev==n)
          return n;
}
```

I call and display the function like so:

```
cout<<foo(11)<<endl<<checkpalin(25)<<endl;
```

When I pass any number other than ten and any non palindromic number to `foo` and `checkpalin` respectively I always get the following output:

> 1
>
> 16640

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: @GregorMcGregor yea thats what, what is happening if the conditions are not met?

Answer (score 2):

Your function definitions don't specify what to return if the condition is *not* true. A function must always return *something*, so it just returns junk (although it may well be *predictable* junk, the value is *undefined*).

You should rewrite your functions like this:

```
int foo()
{
   if (n==10)
      return n;
   else
      return 0;
}
```